# windows backup program with easy restore

Tags: windows-7, backup, data-recovery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any good RESTORE software for Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/110944/is-there-any-good-restore-software-for-windows)

I'm running windows 7 64 bit, i'm looking for a backup solution that will allow me to easily restore my files after a reformat. I have my OS drive and a 2nd hard drive for media. I would like to back these drives up to a external drive. For some reason my windows 7 backup is corrupted and all i get are errors, so that's out. What is another good and easy solution to get back up quickly after a reformat?

Comment: For the "after a reformat" usage scenario: duplicate of [Want to create a system image](http://superuser.com/questions/92224/want-to-create-a-system-image), [Is there any good RESTORE software for Windows?](http://superuser.com/questions/110944/is-there-any-good-restore-software-for-windows) and [Restore complete PC from another computer](http://superuser.com/questions/107809/restore-complete-pc-from-another-computer). For the normal backup usage: [ What backup software for Windows?](http://superuser.com/questions/886/what-backup-software-for-windows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you know what is wrong with windows backup? If it is failing due to some file system problems, you are likely to run into those again when using a third party backup tool.

Have you run the windows disk check tool?

Comment: Sounds like a comment, not an answer to the easy restore part?

Answer (score 0):

It's not free but Acronis Ture Image Home makes both backing up and restoring incredibly easy.
You can choose to back up / restore either: Entire Drives, Entire Partitions, Folders and files.

Restoring is simply a matter of booting from the CD (Or keypress on boot if you have this feature installed) choosing the file you wish to restore, and selecting the correct options.

The GUI is very intuitive, the files it creates cab be heavily compressed upon creation, the restore process seems to be quite quick. I can restore a whole laptop in under 15 minutes on normal compression over a Gigabit LAN.